# Select minimum value in group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table

```
ID,  name, pay1, pay2
 1     a,    3,    2
 2     b,   12,    4
 3     b,    4,    8
 4     c,    8,    7
 5     c,    5,    2
 6     a,    7,    1
```

I would like to select rows where pay1 + pay2 is minimum for every name. So, I would like to get

```
 ID,  name, pay1, pay2
 1     a,    3,    2
 3     b,    4,    8
 5     c,    5,    2
```

Any idea how to do that in SQL Server? Thanks

Comment: @MitchWheat to select rows with name and min pay1 + pay2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a ranking function:

```
with minpay as
(
  select *
    , payrank = row_number() over (partition by name order by pay1 + pay2, ID)
  from pay
)
select ID
  , name
  , pay1
  , pay2
from minpay
where payrank = 1
order by name
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b522/4).

Answer (score 3):

OP doesn't mention how possible ties are to be treated, but:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 join
(select id, sum(pay1 + pay2) as sumpay 
from table1  
group by id) s on t1.id = s.id
join 
(select name, min(pay1 + pay2) as sumpay 
from table1 
group by name) t on t.sumpay = s.sumpay
```

I posted this and then saw Ian's answer which is clearer.

[SQLFiddle with Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66299/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option.

This one will display ties for minimum values.
As @MitchWheat points out the question does not specify how to handle those.

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Name, a.Pay1, a.Pay2
FROM [table] a INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Name, MIN(Pay1 + Pay2) as MinPay
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY Name
) b ON a.Name = b.Name
    AND a.Pay1 + a.Pay2 = b.MinPay
```